# Centering a checkbox without a caption inside a TGridPanel

Tags: delphi, vcl

Searched all over Google and I'm afraid I can't find an answer to this.

Here is my current situation:
[image: Before]

Instead of having those checkbox aligned to the left I want them centered like so (photoshopped obviously):
[image]

Anybody know how to achieve this with VCL? Thanks.

Edit: 
These components are inside a TGridPanel and for whatever reason the Left and Top properties have no effect on the position of the component in the cell. I have also looked for any layout properties with no luck.

Comment: Is this arithmetics suitable for your case? `checkbox.left := (cell.width - checkbox.width) div 2`

Comment: I aplogise, I should have mentioned that these components are inside a TGridPanel and for whatever reason the Left and Top properties have no effect on the position of the component in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

The controls inside the *TGridPanel* are automatically center-aligned. If you reduce the width of the checkboxes to the correct value it should be centered as requested. Be aware that if you reduce the size too much the checkbox will shrink.

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work. Because the TCheckbox components have a caption property, the checkbox is always to the left or right of the text. Regardless of what I set the width to it didn't make a difference. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I checked in Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1 and it actually works. What Delphi version do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately due to various components not being up to date we're stuck in XE5.

Comment: If a checkbox's `Caption` is blank, you should be able to set its `Width` to the size of the checkbox image (or close to it, accounting for spacing between the checkbox and its Caption).  An alternative would be to find a 3rd party checkbox control that allows the extra spacing to be disabled. Or, create your own custom checkbox control from `TCustomControl` that renders a checkbox image. Or just use a `TImage` or `TPaintBox` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution although it's rather messy. But for future reference I had to create a panel for every single cell in my GridPanel then that allowed me to set the left padding property of the panel to push my TCheckboxes over.

[image]

Yes it's super inefficient but it's the best I've got so far. Also fixes my issue of wanting to show the cell outlines inside the GridPanel.